# How do I combine two beta priors?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, prior

The problem is,
Manufacturer receives 30% chips from A, and 70% chips from B.
Both A and B has Beta prior distribution for defective rate.
During inspection of 100 chips, 10 chips were found to be defective. Find the posterior distribution for defective rate.

My approach
Since the prior is beta, and the distribution is binomial, I know the posterior should be beta distribution, but I do not know how to deal with 'two beta priors'.

To summarize, my question is how to incorporate two beta priors.

Comment: What are the hyperparameters for the prior distributions?  Do you know which of the 10 chips came from which manufacturer?

Comment: Parameters for priors are not known, but the problem states A produces 2% defect and B produces 10% defect. Knowing both are beta priors, I assumes priors to be Beta(98, 2) and Beta(90, 10).
Which of the 10 chips came from where is not known.